# Modify awk code

Tags: awk

I would like to print a row of input file 11 if contains less than two strings found in NV_11.tab. Now is not catching strings in file 11 because is looking for exact match. Script needs a cleaning to catch them. I tried adding [^0-9] next to $i but seems this is not allowed.

Thanks, Bernardo

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}
       {
        c=0;
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
            if($i in a){c++}
        } 

       } 
       c<=1;' NV_1.tab 11

#NV_1.tab
HS302
HS303
HS304
HS305
HS319
HS321
HS322
HS323
HS324
HS326
HS327
HS328
HS329
HS330
HS331
HS332
HPSD74

#11
HPNK_11595  HS302_01873 HS303_01073
HPNK_11596  HPNK_11596  HPS_02673   HS302_01873

#current output
HPNK_11595  HS302_01873 HS303_01073
HPNK_11596  HPNK_11596  HPS_02673   HS302_01873

#desired output
HPNK_11596  HPNK_11596  HPS_02673   HS302_01873
```

Comment: You are trying to prefix match the words from `11` against the strings in `NV_1.tab`. So `HS302_01873` matches `HS302`?

Comment: Printing line of file 11 when only one match of NV_1.tab is OK, two or more no.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question was trying to figure out how you were wanting to match so as to get your desired output. So `HPNK_11595  HS302_01873 HS303_01073` fails your test because `HS302_01873` matches `HS302` and `HS303_01073` matches `HS303`?

Comment: Agree, this is why HPNK_11595 HS302_01873 HS303_01073 is not in the desired output.

Comment: Maybe misunderstood. I'm trying to prefix match the words from NV_1.tab against the strings in 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I see to do this is something like this.

Inside the `for` loop add

```
s=$i
gsub(/_.*$/, "", s)
```

and then replace `($i in a)` with `(s in a)`.

Comment: Great answer Etan. Your are removing everything starting from the underscore and then using this as the string.

Comment: @Bernardo Right. The only other alternative I could see was to drop the use of `in` and loop over the fields in `a` manually which seems much worse and almost certainly much slower.

Comment: +1 and a tiny nitpick - you just need `sub()`, not `gsub()`. nbd though.